AZCopy Sync Skipping Zero Byte Files in Azure Blob Storage
I am attempting to replicate Azure blob storage to another subscription's blob storage using AZCopy Sync. The process works well, but it skips certain files.
To represent empty folders, dummy files (0 bytes) are created with the dummy name as present in below image. However, with AZCopy Sync, all the 0-byte files are not being copied, resulting in the absence of empty folders in the destination.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

To achieve your requirement, you can follow below procedure:
To create dummy files in folder to represent empty folders use ADF copy activity, select dummy file as source and select destination with folder name.
Source:

Destination:

Then the inputs folder will create with empty blob as shown below:

Then you will be able to copy empty folders from source to destination using below command:
azcopy sync "https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/source<SASToken>" "https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/destination<SASToken>"


The empty folder also copies to the destination with 0-byte block blob successfully as shown below:

Alternatively, According to  this  Azure blob storage doesn't support empty folders, that may be the reason for empty folders are missing in the target storage account. If you want to work with Empty folders check  Enable hierarchical namespace  while creating storage account as shown below:

Then the storage account behaves like ADLS gen2 account and it will support empty folders. If the target storage account is already created, then upgrade it ADLS gen2 by using option  Data Lake Gen2 upgrade  as shown below:

Then you will be able to copy empty folders successfully.

Hi Bhavani, Thank you and appreciate your prompt response. I have started originally with ADF with Copy DataPipeline and option to retain folder structure but some how after run of ADF it was creating separate file for each folder name so I aborted on this approach. My customer is using Azure blob storage for a reason so I don't have flexibility to go for Gen2 storage.

Then why don't you try with ADLS account?

I have figured out the solution by using include-directory-stub flag, azcopy include all 0 byte files and keep folder structure intact.
azcopy sync "source" "destination" --recursive --delete-destination true --include-directory-stub=true

Thank you so much for your suggestions.
